# Merge multiple API JSON (nested) data to a dataframe in R

Tags: r, json, dataframe, api, nested

I want to merge data from multiple API calls into one dataframe (api resource is the employee ID). The goal is to create a new dataframe (or add new attributes to existing retrieved `employees` dataframe). For example the dataframe will have all the attributes from `employees` + the attributes  `department, top level department, rooms`.

Here are my 3 tries that dont work:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)
library(dplyr)

# set API endpoint and parameters
api_endpoint <- "https://at.tuke.sk/api/employee"
params <- list(query = "data", type = "json")

# make API request
response <- GET(api_endpoint, query = params)

# convert response to JSON format
employees <- fromJSON(content(response, "text"), flatten = TRUE)
employees <- employees[!duplicated(employees$idEmployee), ] 


# list of employee ids
employee_ids <- employees[[1]]

for(i in 1:length(employee_ids)) {
  
  # Build the API URL with the new county code
  API_URL <- paste0('https://at.tuke.sk/api/employee/', employee_ids[i])
  
  # Store the raw and processed API results in temporary objects
  temp_raw <- GET(API_URL)
  temp_list <- fromJSON(rawToChar(temp_raw$content), flatten = TRUE)
  
  library(plyr)
  #employee_df <- rbind.fill(employees, temp_list)
  #employee_df <- data.table::rbindlist(temp_list, fill = TRUE)

  #employee_df <- bind_rows(employees, temp_list)
  
}


###############################################################
rf <- GET("https://at.tuke.sk/api/employee/")
rfc <- content(rf)

json_file <- sapply(rfc, function(x) {
  x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
  unlist(x)
  as.data.frame(t(x))
})

library(data.table)
data.table::rbindlist(json_file, fill= TRUE)
##########################################################################

library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
# list of employee ids
#employee_ids <- c(77824, 6089, 6741, 1628, 9351, 16195, 9238, 9282, 6084, 77604)
employee_ids <- employees[[1]]
# create a data frame to store employee information
employee_df <- data.frame(
  id = integer(),
  first_name = character(),
  last_name = character(),
  email = character(),
  phone = character(),
  department = character(),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
# loop through employee ids
for (id in employee_ids) {
  # set API endpoint and parameters
  api_endpoint <- paste0("https://at.tuke.sk/api/employee/", id)
  params <- list(query = "data", type = "json")
  # make API request
  response <-
    try(GET(api_endpoint, query = params, content_type("application/json")), silent = TRUE)
  # convert response to JSON format
  employee <-
    try(fromJSON(content(response, "text"), flatten = TRUE), silent = TRUE)
  # extract required fields and add to dataframe
  if (inherits(employee, "list") && !is.null(employee$department$name)) {
    employee_info <- data.frame(
      id = employee$employee$idEmployee,
      first_name = employee$employee$firstName,
      last_name = employee$employee$lastName,
      email = employee$employee$email,
      phone = employee$employee$phone,
      department = employee$department$name,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
    employee_df <- rbind(employee_df, employee_info)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to flatten those responses, following example requests details for the first 5 id-s:

```r
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# main list
empl_main <- fromJSON("https://at.tuke.sk/api/employee?query=data&type=json") %>% 
  as_tibble()

# details for first 5 id-s
empl_details <- map(empl_main$idEmployee[1:5], 
                    \(idE) fromJSON(paste0("https://at.tuke.sk/api/employee/",idE), flatten = TRUE)) %>% 
  tibble(empl = .) %>% 
  unnest_wider(empl) %>% 
  # from 'employee' hoist only 'idEmployee' for joining, drop the rest
  hoist ("employee", "idEmployee") %>% 
  select (-employee) %>% 
  # unnest 'department', 'topLevelDepartment', 'rooms'
  unnest_wider(c(department, topLevelDepartment, rooms), names_sep ="_")

# join 2 tibbles
empl_j <- left_join(empl_main, empl_details)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(idEmployee, publonsUrl)`
```

Result:

```r
# 1443 x 75 tibble, includes flattened details for first 5 id-s

glimpse(empl_j)
#> Rows: 1,443
#> Columns: 75
#> $ idEmployee                                <int> 77824, 6089, 6741, 1628, 935…
#> $ firstName                                 <chr> "Tomáš", "Norbert", "Františ…
#> $ lastName                                  <chr> "Adam", "Ádám", "Adamčík", "…
#> $ titleBefore                               <chr> "Ing.", "doc. Ing.", "prof. …
#> $ titleAfter                                <chr> NA, "PhD.", "CSc.", "PhD.", …
#> $ email                                     <chr> "tomas.ada....ke.sk", "norbe…
#> $ phone                                     <chr> "+401 55 602...6", "+421 55 …
#> $ web                                       <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, …
#> $ login                                     <chr> "ta...kn", "an...wq", "fa...…
#> $ employmentType                            <chr> "D", "P", "P", "P", "N", "D"…
#> $ idDepartment                              <int> 104004, 104009, 109003, 1051…
#> $ idRoom                                    <int> 481, 249, 3990, 37, 2086, 19…
#> $ idRoomEmployeePosition                    <int> 3358, 1830, 3189, 1609, 1960…
#> $ position                                  <chr> "doktorand", "docent", "prof…
#> $ positionEn                                <chr> "PhD Student", "Associate Pr…
#> $ color                                     <chr> "#EAAA00", "#EAAA00", "#41B6…
#> $ publonsUrl                                <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, …
#> $ fullName                                  <chr> "Ing. Tomáš Adam", "doc. Ing…
#> $ orcidUrl                                  <chr> NA, NA, "https://orcid.org/0…
#> $ department_idDepartment                   <int> 104004, NA, 109003, NA, 1901…
#> $ department_acronym                        <chr> "KKUI", NA, "KA", NA, "ÚVVaD…
#> $ department_name                           <chr> "Katedra kybernetiky a umele…
#> $ department_nameEn                         <chr> "Department of Cybernetics a…
#> $ department_color                          <chr> "#EAAA00", NA, "#41B6E6", NA…
#> $ department_web                            <chr> "https://kkui.fei.tuke.sk", …
#> $ topLevelDepartment_idDepartment           <int> 1040, NA, 1090, NA, 1900, NA…
#> $ topLevelDepartment_acronym                <chr> "FEI", NA, "LF", NA, "R", NA…
#> $ topLevelDepartment_name                   <chr> "Fakulta elektrotechniky a i…
#> $ topLevelDepartment_nameEn                 <chr> "Faculty of Electrical Engin…
#> $ topLevelDepartment_color                  <chr> "#EAAA00", NA, "#41B6E6", NA…
#> $ topLevelDepartment_web                    <chr> "http://fei.tuke.sk", NA, "h…
#> $ rooms_idRoomEmployeePosition              <int> 3358, NA, 3189, NA, 1960, NA…
#> $ rooms_idRoom                              <int> 481, NA, 3990, NA, 2086, NA,…
#> $ rooms_idEmployee                          <int> 77824, NA, 6741, NA, 9351, N…
#> $ rooms_idEmployeePosition                  <int> 29, NA, 23, NA, 131, NA, NA,…
#> $ rooms_orderOnLabel                        <int> 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ rooms_idDepartment                        <int> 104004, NA, 109003, NA, 1901…
#> $ rooms_room.idRoom                         <int> 481, NA, 3990, NA, 2086, NA,…
#> $ rooms_room.idRoomType                     <int> 4, NA, 4, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA,…
#> $ rooms_room.idBuilding                     <int> 1, NA, 153, NA, 20, NA, NA, …
#> $ rooms_room.number                         <chr> "154", NA, "047", NA, "A119"…
#> $ rooms_room.name                           <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, "Referát dom…
#> $ rooms_room.nameEn                         <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, …
#> $ rooms_room.level                          <chr> "1. poschodie", NA, "Prízemi…
#> $ rooms_room.roomType.idRoomType            <int> 4, NA, 4, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA,…
#> $ rooms_room.roomType.name                  <chr> "Kancelária", NA, "Kancelári…
#> $ rooms_room.roomType.nameEn                <chr> "Office", NA, "Office", NA, …
#> $ rooms_room.roomType.pictogram             <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, …
#> $ rooms_room.building.idBuilding            <int> 1, NA, 153, NA, 20, NA, NA, …
#> $ rooms_room.building.name                  <chr> "V4", NA, "R7-16", NA, "L9",…
#> $ rooms_room.building.address               <chr> "Vysokoškolská 4", NA, "Ramp…
#> $ rooms_room.building.latitude              <dbl> 48.73419, NA, NA, NA, 48.730…
#> $ rooms_room.building.longitude             <dbl> 21.24496, NA, NA, NA, 21.245…
#> $ rooms_room.building.levels                <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, …
#> $ rooms_employee.idEmployee                 <int> 77824, NA, 6741, NA, 9351, N…
#> $ rooms_employee.firstName                  <chr> "Tomáš", NA, "František", NA…
#> $ rooms_employee.lastName                   <chr> "Adam", NA, "Adamčík", NA, "…
#> $ rooms_employee.titleBefore                <chr> "Ing.", NA, "prof. Ing.", NA…
#> $ rooms_employee.titleAfter                 <chr> NA, NA, "CSc.", NA, "PhD.", …
#> $ rooms_employee.email                      <chr> "tomas.ad....uke.sk", NA, "f…
#> $ rooms_employee.phone                      <chr> "+4.1 55 602...6", NA, "+421…
#> $ rooms_employee.web                        <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, …
#> $ rooms_employee.login                      <chr> "ta857kn", NA, "fa777fa", NA…
#> $ rooms_employee.employmentType             <chr> "D", NA, "P", NA, "N", NA, N…
#> $ rooms_employee.idDepartment               <int> 104004, NA, 109003, NA, 1901…
#> $ rooms_employee.fullName                   <chr> "Ing. Tomáš Adam", NA, "prof…
#> $ rooms_employeePosition.idEmployeePosition <int> 29, NA, 23, NA, 131, NA, NA,…
#> $ rooms_employeePosition.name               <chr> "doktorand", NA, "profesor",…
#> $ rooms_employeePosition.nameEn             <chr> "PhD Student", NA, "Professo…
#> $ rooms_department.idDepartment             <int> 104004, NA, 109003, NA, 1901…
#> $ rooms_department.acronym                  <chr> "KKUI", NA, "KA", NA, "ÚVVaD…
#> $ rooms_department.name                     <chr> "Katedra kybernetiky a umele…
#> $ rooms_department.nameEn                   <chr> "Department of Cybernetics a…
#> $ rooms_department.color                    <chr> "#EAAA00", NA, "#41B6E6", NA…
#> $ rooms_department.web                      <chr> "https://kkui.fei.tuke.sk", …
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>